How to remove encoded characters in a column?
I'm cleaning a dataset and there's a column named 'city' which the city name has encoded characters.
My first try was to use the method decoded, but then I noticed the city names were in string format:
Example of encoded name: S\xC3\xA3o Paulo
So I took a look in the whole dataset and made a dictionary with all encoded characters.
d = {'\\\\xC3\\\\xA3': 'ã',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xA1': 'á',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xAD': 'í',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xA9': 'é',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xA2': 'â',
     'D\\xC3\\xBC': 'ü',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xB3': 'ó',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xA7': 'ç',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xBA': 'õ',
     '\\\\xC3\\\\xA5' : 'å'}

for k in d.keys():
    df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace(k, d[k]) 

It's works but I'm not sure if this way is the better and the faster way to fix this.

Does this answer your question? Process escape sequences in a string in Python. Here's a quick example: s = 'S\xC3\xA3o Paulo' print(bytes(s, 'latin-1').decode('unicode_escape')) >>> São Paulo. Note that I've changed the encoding used in the linked answer from 'utf-8' to 'latin-1', but the principle is the same.

That said, the accepted answer I linked to has some issues. This answer on the same page digs a little deeper and may work better.

The immediate problem with your attempt is that \xc3 is a literal character, but you are attempting to replace the character sequence backslash, backslash, x, c, 3 (with two backslashes even).

you can use a regex pattern like r'.?([\x80-\xFF]{2}).?$' to match the two non-ascii character sequence and use it as a key in your dictionary. Note that the 'latin-1' charset contains only certain western European characters.

Could not get the suggested solution to work. This works instead   s.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
